# reasons for requesting virtual appearance post-COVID

Tags: covid-19, court, appearance

An attorney friend wants to continue appearing in court virtually.  The problem is that he is now (post-COVID shutdown) expected to appear in person.  What are the acceptable reasons an attorney can use to request permission to appear virtually?  We are in New York.  Most of his work is as assigned counsel -- but not all.

Edit to add: I can imagine various reasons which would be valid for him, but I'm not sure if they would seem reasonable.

The transition out of COVID-induced virtual work can be awkward and confusing in many types of work.  Respectful comments much appreciated.

Comment: Huh. Is this a lawyer's friend seeking legal advice for the lawyer from someone on the Internet? Practically speaking, if the other party doesn't object, a simple "I can't be arsed to appear in person" should be enough. May add that there is some significant amount of travel involved, other matters in other courts the same day etc.

Comment: post-covid? are we in post-covid now? a lot of countries are still on lockdown or have quarantine stuff

Comment: @BCLC - True.  I was only talking about my area.  Of course we're not out of the woods yet but case numbers have plummeted, and have stayed extremely low for several months.  Courts are making adjustments.

Comment: Here I think I can say that we are "post-COVID shutdown"(not post-COVID).  Even movie theaters have re-opened.